# converting a data frame cell into NaN using boolean mask

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe(df) which looks like this:[image]

I want to convert all of the cells that have "..." into cells containing NaN. I created a boolean mask
`mask = df['Energy Supply per Capita'] !="…"`
to isolate the cells that have numbers but when I go to apply the mask
`df.where(mask).head()`
it converts the entire row into NaN instead of just the one cell so that df looks like this: [image]

how can I make it so that only the one specific cell is converted into NaN?

Comment: `df.replace({"...": pd.NA}, inplace=True)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace()`.

```
df.replace({"...": pd.NA}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use numeric with errors coerce

```
cols = ['Energy Supply per Capita']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Can you explain what that will do? I tried searching it up but I'm still confused.

Comment: I think you get the answer so congrats, BTW I suggest using a built-in method named `pd.to_numeric` which can be used to covert all possible kinds of data to numerical type, in addition, with the argument `errors='coerce'` it would convert your `...` data to `NaN` instead of throwing an error.